# How to execute mongo shell command from javascript

Tags: mongodb

In a mongo shell window, I'd like to periodically run a script that will display various stats on the database activity, before displaying the stats, I'd like to clear the screen. There is a "cls" command in the mongo shell, but I am not able to execute it from within the javascript.

```
function stats () {
while(1) {
    cls;
    print("display stats");
    sleep(5000);
}}
```

The line with the "cls" is not recognized.

Thank you for any suggestions,
Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the first glance it seemed that you won't be able to do it. According to the docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/): "You cannot use any shell helper (e.g. use , show dbs, etc.) inside the JavaScript file because they are not valid JavaScript.".

One option was to fill the screen with empty lines:

```
function clearIt () { for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) { print() } }
clearIt()
```

However, thanks to @NeilLunn pointing it out there seems to be a solution:

```
function clearIt () { run('clear') }
clearIt()
```

This would execute system command which will clear your terminal screen. I don't know how reliable it is (see `man clear` -> depends if it can figure out how to clear screen) and this works only on POSIX systems. On Windows you would have to replace `clear` with `cls`:

```
function clearIt () { run('cls') }
```

*Additional:*

I looked up the source code of mongo shell (src/mongo/shell/linenoise.cpp). Here is how it clears the screen:

```
void linenoiseClearScreen( void ) {
#ifdef _WIN32
    COORD coord = {0, 0};
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO inf;
    HANDLE screenHandle = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( screenHandle, &inf );
    SetConsoleCursorPosition( screenHandle, coord );
    DWORD count;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacterA( screenHandle, ' ', inf.dwSize.X * inf.dwSize.Y, coord, &count );
#else
    if ( write( 1, "\x1b[H\x1b[2J", 7 ) <= 0 ) return;
#endif
}
```

In case you feel like trying to implement your own screen cleaning function by filling screen with chars.

Comment: That only applies to the listed helpers. There are some functions available that get loaded to the shell even when the script is invoked from the command line.

Comment: Yeah. But you don't need to wrap that in a function as it already is a function. Just: run('cls') . That's obviously on windows.

Answer (score 0):

```
> help admin
    ls([path])                      list files
    pwd()                           returns current directory
    listFiles([path])               returns file list
    hostname()                      returns name of this host
    cat(fname)                      returns contents of text file as a string
    removeFile(f)                   delete a file or directory
    load(jsfilename)                load and execute a .js file
    run(program[, args...])         spawn a program and wait for its completion
    runProgram(program[, args...])  same as run(), above
    sleep(m)                        sleep m milliseconds
    getMemInfo()                    diagnostic
```

This shows the `run` and `runProgram` commands along with some other helpers. The `program` argument is a string.

Comment: Which one of these does the job?

Comment: As mentioned in the answer there are `run` and `runProgram`. All of these are loaded javascript functions.